# Multiple Splits in Java

Tags: java

I've a string which contains following data:

```
user_id:16|login_id:6|pass_id:6|email:abc@abc.com|product_id:|name:Mike|created_date:20120101:12:22|address:US
```

How can I get the each field in Java?

I can use split but then later how would I get the colon separator? Also, how can I handle created_date as it has 2 colons, so I won't be able to separate by colon.

Also, note that product_id is empty.

Any sample in Java 1.6 is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First solution comes in my mind is: (Not sure this is efficient)

1. Split string by  `|`
2. Use substring and indexOf of String class to get result.

Example:

```
String str = "user_id:16|login_id:6|pass_id:6|email:abc@abc.com|product_id:|name:Mike|created_date:20120101:12:22|address:US";
String[] strArr = str.split("\\|");
for (String string : strArr) {
    System.out.println("First part: " + string.substring(0, string.indexOf(":")));
    System.out.println("Second part: " + string.substring(string.indexOf(":")+1));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Assumption: No `:` comes in name(first part). ie first `:` will always come after the complete name(first part) and then value(second part).

Comment: Thanks. But how can I store them in variables like userId, productId, email, etc?

Comment: @Mike: In this solution, you have to use `if..else` or if you are using java 7 then you can use `switch` over first part of the `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Look you can use this technique (delimiting strings) only when you are pretty sure of the fact that the data you are getting from the source will always strictly follow this standard.

Find some other technique otherwise, most preferably XML or JSON.